# How to find When a Facebook User has Last Used my App, using Graph API? 

Tags: android, facebook-graph-api, multiplayer

I am an Indie Game Developer, working on a multi-player Android game. I now need to implement a feature, where **I want to show my Facebook Friends Activity of my Game.**

I already know how to Identify how many of my friends are playing my Game (Or using my App).
But, now I also what to display the last time they played my Game.

So, to summarize :

**How to find when a Facebook User has last used my App, using Graph API? 
Assume that my Game has an authorized Facebook session of every User playing it.
Is this even possible?**

I know that I can write my own server-side code to track user activity on my Game. But I think I can avoid all that, if Facebook can give me the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I know that I can write my own server-side code to track user activity on my Game.

That’s what you’ll have to do.

> But I think I can avoid all that, if Facebook can give me the information.

No, this info is not available anywhere through the API or FQL.

Comment: Yeah, it actually makes sense. I was thinking too Greedy, wanting to relying on Facebook to do stuff. :-) I will write up some server side scripts, then. 

Thanks CBroe.